# undefined method `total_pages' error in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

Am using Devise for authentication and cancancan for authorization.cancancan is working fine for some controller but throws undefined method error for some screens..

assessments_controller.rb

```
    def index    
     @projects = Project.find_by_sql("SELECT project_id, project_name FROM projects WHERE company_id = "+ current_dashboard_user.company_id.to_s +
                                " ORDER BY project_name")

     getProjectId

     getResult #get search result

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
    end    
   end

   def getResult    
    #Search Result page
    if (@project_id != nil && @project_id != "") then
      @assessments = Assessment.find_by_sql("SELECT assess.assessment_id, assess.company_id, assess.project_id, assess.release_cycle_no, 
                                             assess.assessment_description, DATE_FORMAT(assess.start_date,'%d/%m/%Y') start_date_display,
                                             DATE_FORMAT(assess.end_date,'%d/%m/%Y') end_date_display, assess.project_phase_id, pp.project_phase_name,
                                             CASE WHEN assess.closed_status = 'Y' THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Open' END AS closed_status
                                             FROM assessments assess, project_phases pp
                                             WHERE assess.company_id = " + current_dashboard_user.company_id.to_s +
                                             " AND assess.project_id = " + @project_id.to_s + 
                                             " AND assess.project_phase_id = pp.project_phase_id ORDER BY assess.assessment_id DESC")

      @assessments = @assessments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
  end
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9ccee7be3e7fa2df2bca

My views.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/272e6cc05e01d526ef0a

the error i got is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hozKw.jpg

Comment: `total_pages` is a method of `will_paginate`, not `cancancan` itself.

Comment: @blelump the problem is with cancan because in that controller cancancan couldn't authorize assesments resources as per load_and_authorize_resources method. So we had to skip for this index action and manually check the authorization index for each resources. The answer has been implemented and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to define authorization manually for your index action.

```
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:getProjectId, :getResult, :index]

  def index    
    @projects = Project.find_by_sql("SELECT project_id, project_name FROM projects WHERE company_id = "+ current_dashboard_user.company_id.to_s +
                                    " ORDER BY project_name")
    authorize! :read, @projects
    getProjectId

    getResult #get search result
    authorize! :read, @assessments
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end    
  end
```

Comment: Cancan performs authorization only on controller actions, not all third party methods. Skipping loading resource for `:getProjectId, :getResult` has no effect here.

Comment: Yah those two actions can bw removed.